# How return is working from array_map PHP

Tags: php, return, array-map

I'm fairly new to PHP, but I understand once PHP hits a `return` in a function, it will exit out of the function and return to where it was called.

I am confused to how or why in the function below `array_map()` starts with `return` and has another inside the function.

```
function array_plucked($toPluck, $arr) {
return array_map(function($item) use($toPluck) {
    return $item[$toPluck];
}, $arr); }
```

Also each time it loops through the array what exactly happening to `$item[$toPluck]`, and where is the result being stored?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Good question! Okay, let's clean this up a bit:

```
function array_pluck($key, $array)
{
    return array_map(function ($item) use ($key) {
        return $item[$key];
    }, $array);
}
```

It's a bit easier to understand this way.

First, the goal of this function is to return a *one-dimensional array of the values of a specific key* from a multidimensional array. Here are examples:

```
$testArray = array(
    array("xxx" => "hello", "yyy" => "goodbye"),
    array("xxx" => "hi", "yyy" => "bye"),
    array("xxx" => "hey", "yyy" => "peace"),
);

php > var_dump(array_pluck('xxx', $testArray));
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "hello"
  [1]=>
  string(2) "hi"
  [2]=>
  string(3) "hey"
}

php > var_dump(array_pluck('yyy', $testArray));
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(7) "goodbye"
  [1]=>
  string(3) "bye"
  [2]=>
  string(5) "peace"
}
php >
```

As you can see, this is returning `$testArray[<index>]['xxx']` and `$testArray[<index>]['yyy']` respectively, for each array inside the parent array.

Now to explain what's going on with the `return`. The [`array_map()`](https://secure.php.net/array_map) function takes a function (or "[Callable](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php)") as the first parameter, and an array as the second parameter. The function is run for each element in the array, and then `array_map()` adds the return value of that function to the new array that `array_map()` returns.

This is called an [*anonymous function*](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php):

```
function ($item) use ($key) {
    return $item[$key];
}
```

It is just like any other function, except it doesn't have a name, and it does have the `use (...)` syntax. The `use ($key)` means to "import" `$key` from the outer function (`array_pluck()`), so it can be used inside this anonymous function. Each element of `$testArray` in the example above, gets passed to this anonymous function as `$item`. When `return $item[$key]` occurs, only the anonymous function returns (exits), and the `array_map()` continues on to the next element.

Comment: Good answer, but: "then array_map() replaces the original element with the return value of that function, in the new array that array_map() returns" - it's not clear whether the original array is replaced or a new array is created. I would write something like: "then array_map() adds the return value of that function to the new array that array_map() returns".

Comment: Thanks! I have used your edit. That does sound much more clear.

Comment: No problem @programming2music, glad to help! If your question is completely answered, click the checkbox next to the answer to accept it.